# Unable to install Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I have Toshiba Satellite C850-B798 with Windows 7 x64 installed.

I downloaded Ubuntu desktop x64 ISO and burn it to flash memory by universal installer, when I choose to boot from flash it give me nothing only black screen, I enter to BIOS to disable secure boot but I didn't find this option, also I didn't find UEFI or CSM.

I updated the BIOS to the last version 6.80 but nothing new happened, and I installed Ubuntu x86 but also the same results.

I installed win 8.1 x64 and I tried to find UEFI but I didn't find it.

I tried the ISO on vmware and it works well, also flash memory works well.

Simply, I tried all mentioned solutions but I still can't install Ubuntu, Why?

---

I also tried unetbootin, same results.
There is no problem with boot order, and I installed win 8.1 by the same flash and same boot order and it worked fine

Comment: read this article http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Comment: I read it, I discovered that my bios doesn't support UEFI، so as the article it must boot normally, but also I cannot boot.

Comment: please output the `sudo parted -l` Are you trying to dual-boot? Or install only Ubuntu?

Comment: No, I want to install only ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Try and create the bootable USB with this http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net. I had the same issue,  mine worked with this.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enter your BIOS and look at your system boot order. I suspect that booting from a bootable CD/DVD disk is not enabled or is ordered wrong (i.e. listed after curretnly installed operating system). A USB may also work as it could have a different boot priority in the BIOS from a CD/DVD

Comment: It's not boot order problem , I'm very sure, it's some thing else and maybe I should to ask another question to can get the proper explanation

Answer (score 0):

Finally, Ubuntu installed on my laptop, I used unetbootin but with the option of install iso on the C partition and then it restarted and give me console to choose if I want boot in win 8 or in unetbootin. thanks every body, but I hop to fix this issue cause booting with unetbootin is not efficient cause when partitioning I can't delete the C partition cause the iso installed on it and I will be obliged to use dual operating system .

Comment: Kindly, any explanation about why I can't install Ubuntu till use unetbootin with option of extract the ubuntu.iso on same Windows partition?